# Need help to send email with PHPMailer

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send email. Everything is working fine except one thing. The email could not be send if the subject contains an UTF-8 character. I've set `$mail->CharSet="UTF-8"`.

Comment: What errors do you get? Whats your current code? The email gets sent if the subject contains "regular chars"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to encode subject to handle utf8 characters...

```
$sendsubject= "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Subject = $sendsubject;
```